# What platforms does Tor work on?

Tags: source-code, platform

I'm looking for a list of the operating systems/architectures Tor runs on while being supported by the Tor Project, and if it can be compiled on other system not directly supported by the Tor Project.

1. What platforms are currently supported by the Tor Project, i.e. for which platforms does the Tor project provide packages?
2. What platforms can Tor be compiled on and is known to work on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tor runs on many platforms; below is a list of those on which it's known to work.

## Microsoft Windows

- Windows 98 SE (Version <= 2.3.x )
- Windows ME (Version <= 2.3.x )
- Windows NT (Version <= 2.3.x )
- Windows 2000 (Version <= 2.3.x )
- Windows 2000 Server (Version <= 2.3.x )
- Windows XP
- Windows 2003 Server
- Windows Vista
- Windows 2008 Server
- Windows 7
- Windows 2012 Server
- Windows 8
- Windows 8.1

## Apple-based platforms

- Mac OS X
- iOS

## Unix-like platforms

- BSD variants

  - NetBSD
  - OpenBSD
  - FreeBSD
  - DragonFly BSD
- GNU/Linux distributions

  - Debian
  - Fedora
  - SUSE
  - Gentoo
  - Arch
  - Most others
- Solaris-based

  - OpenSolaris
  - illumos
  - OpenIndiana

## Mobile platforms

- Android
- Nokia Maemo.

It runs on ARM as well as 32-bit and 64-bit Intel/AMD compatible processors.  In other words, almost everything.

Comment: I don't think we actively support Windows 98/ME.

Comment: @weasel-PeterPalfrader Then this may need to be revised: https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en Under "Expert Bundle."

Comment: Also, You can run into high CPU usage problems in XP.

Answer (score 2):

The current stable version of the expert bundle, 0.2.3.25, works well on all of the listed versions of Windows. The 0.2.4 beta versions don't work on 98SE/ME or Windows 2000.